# Django url pattern multiple Parameters (without pk)

Tags: django, parameters, django-rest-framework, url-pattern

I'm new to the Django Framework and one thing bothers me.

I want a simple Rest Call:

```
www.abc.com/users/1/cantonments/1/
```

If i use 'pk' in the url pattern everything works out of the box (pk, pk1, pk2....).
But i have some permission functionality which expects the parameters in kwargs in the form 'upk' and 'cpk' for user and cantonment. So if i change **pk** to **upk** everything breaks. Somehow the url needs ONE pk.

This works:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/cantonments/(?P<cpk>[0-9]+)/$',
views.CantonmentDetail.as_view()),
```

This doesnt:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<upk>[0-9]+)/cantonments/(?P<cpk>[0-9]+)/$',
views.CantonmentDetail.as_view()),
```

*Is there any way to have an url pattern that does not need one entry with pk?*

P.S. The error:

```
Expected view CantonmentDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

**EDIT:**

My view is simple:

```
# Authenticated User can show Cantonment Detail
class CantonmentDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CantonmentSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Cantonment.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['cpk'])
```

**Edit2:**

I changed get_queryset to get object and it works.

```
def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    obj = queryset.get(pk=self.kwargs['cpk'])
    return obj
```

**Edit3:**
Using

```
lookup_url_kwarg = "cpk"
```

in the class works as well.

Comment: show your views?

Comment: your view.py may problem get argument can add this

Comment: It has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487445/why-the-url-works-with-parameter-pk-and-not-pk2/55487465?noredirect=1#comment97683432_55487465) clearly

Answer (score 0):

May be in your view you are accessing pk variable

urls.py

```
url(r'^users/(?P<upk>[0-9]+)/cantonments/(?P<cpk>[0-9]+)/$',
views.CantonmentDetail.as_view()),
```

views.py

```
class your_class_name(ListView):
    def view_name(self):
        upk=self.kwargs['upk']
        cpk=self.kwargs['cpk']
        print upk, cpk
        ...
```

Hope this is helps you

Comment: This looks really promising. How can i add upk=None etc to my generic class based view?
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can send optional pk using get method with your url like

```
www.abc.com/users/1/cantonments/?&upk=1
```

and url should be

```
url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/cantonments/$',
views.CantonmentDetail.as_view()),
```

and views.py

```
def view_name(request, pk=None):
    upk = request.GET.get('upk')
```

Answer (score 0):

The upk doesn't make any difference to the lookup (because a primary key identifies a single object by design).

So for the view, the [lookup_field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) needs to be set to 'cpk' and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed your view with the new names of the variables?
If you have url like this:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<upk>[0-9]+)/cantonments/(?P<cpk>[0-9]+)/$',
views.CantonmentDetail.as_view()),
```

You shouls update your view like this:

```
def view_name(request, upk=None, cpk=None):
    ...
```