# Why the url works with parameter pk and not pk2?

Tags: python, django

When I try to send `pk2` or any other argument, it raises an `AssertionError`.
What I mean is this that the url

```
path('grade/<str:pk>/', IndividualGrade.as_view(), name="get-grade")
```

doesn't throw an error while the one below causes an error:

```
path('grade/<str:pk2>/', IndividualGrade.as_view(), name="get-grade")
```

My view is fairly simple as below:

```
class IndividualGrade(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    '''    PUT/GET/DELETE grade/{grade:pk}/    '''
    queryset = Grade.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GradeSerializer
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            g1 = Grade.objects.get(grade=kwargs["pk"])
            serializer = GradeSerializer(g1, data=request.data)
            flag = 0
        except Grade.DoesNotExist: # Create a new grade if a grade doesn't exist
            g1 = Grade.objects.get(grade=kwargs["pk"])
            serializer = GradeSerializer(g1, data=request.data)
            flag = 1
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # call update/create here
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I realized `pk2` in the url works if I write my own get function (tried in another view), but I don't know how to fix this without writing my own get. While this have been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318182/django-url-pattern-multiple-parameters-without-pk). But I am still not sure how to fix it without writing my own get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add

```
lookup_field = 'pk2'
```

when you are using something else than pk, which is inbuilt for lookup . when you want something else in the url you need to mention that.

Comment: Gives me an error `Cannot resolve keyword 'pk2' into field. Choices are: StudentList, id, grade`

Comment: ok so you dont have pk2 in the database? then you cant, for that you can only use the fields available in the model

Comment: That makes sense. I am assuming it works the same way if there are pk2 and pk3? I just define `lookup_field = 'pk2'`?